# Authorize.Net AIM Transaction timeout workaround?

Tags: asp.net, api, timeout, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I have written the following code for authorize.NET AIM gateway auth_capture transaction:

```
    try
                {
                    if (transactionAmount == 0)
                    {
                        Logger.WriteInfo("$0 transaction needs no payment Gateway Transaction ");
                    }
        else 
        {
            //This function sends auth_capture request and processes payment based on transaction parameters.
                        TransactionResponse transactionResponse = ProcessPayment(dist, fee);

                        transactionID = transactionResponse.TransactionID;
                        transactionStatus = transactionResponse.Status;
                        serverResponse = transactionResponse.ServerResponse;
                    }
                }
                catch (TimeoutException tex)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                    Logger.WriteError(ex.ToString());
                    Master.ErrorMessage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_MESSAGE"];
                    IEUtils.SendExceptionMail(ex.tex, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_EMAIL_SUBJECT"]);
                    Logger.WriteError(ex.ToString());

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                    Logger.WriteError(ex.ToString());
                    Master.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                    return;
                }
```

The scenario is that if a timeout occurs how can we see whether a transaction has taken place or not and if yes what is the transaction ID? There are methods available that can be used to get settled/unsettled transactions but identifying the most recent transaction requires multiple api calls which is again risky. What can be the most efficient workaround after authorize.Net gateway transaction request timeout?

Comment: Seeing that it was more than a year ago, what solution did you come up with at the end?

Comment: We added some threading for delay and wait for confirmation from Authorize.Net API, and if the transaction is not successful, we show a message to the user that his transaction was unsuccessful.